# Selectively grab Instances for creating a movie

Tags: netlogo

How can I selectively grab only the world and just 2 of 3 plots in my NetLogo model run?

`movie-grab-view` grabs only the world view while other `movie-grab-interface`grabs all. Is the other to way to the aforementioned?

Note: this of course excludes buttons, sliders etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving the unwanted interface items to the edge of the Interface tab, recording the movie, then cropping the movie in movie-editing software to remove the unwanted portion.

Alternatively, you could cover the unwanted interface items with one or more opaque white notes, or cover them with other interface items.

I'm certain nothing exists to automate this process, unless you build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I am not able to cover the buttons. I want to cover the buttons using simulation window.

Comment: I can't find an option to send items back or bring to front. Please elucidate more on the second solution.

Comment: The Z-order is determined by the order in which the widgets are created. There's no way to change the Z-order of existing widgets in the GUI, but you can do edit by editing the .nlogo file in a text editor and changing the order there. (IIRC though the view is always on the bottom? Not 100% sure.)